# open camera from UITableViewCell iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller, cell

I have a UITableView and a UITableViewCell. In every UITableViewCell I want to open gallery or click an image. I normally present UIImageviewController like

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

  [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

How can I present from cell ?

Misha :)

Comment: Present from the controller that contains the UITableView.

Comment: You can call the same method in didSelectrow method!!!!

Comment: @Mr.T I have other buttons in tableViewCell as well. calling in didSelect will effect them too

Comment: @LyndseyScott isn't it possible from my custom cell class ?

Comment: i meant, whatever you do, didSelectRow should be the starting point!!!!

Comment: @Mr.T this might be most stupid question but how I can I differentiate b/w buttons of tableViewCell in tableView ?

Comment: can you please give clarification regarding the buttons you have in your table cell? After tap on table cell the camera opens or after the tap on button on table cell, camera open. What happens after camera opens?

Comment: @Mr.T The custom cell is handing the button tap. The table view delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not involved here.

Comment: @Mr.T one opens camera, other shows drop down ,and a third one perform addition on two values (in some cells) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution is to use proper MVC design. Have your custom cell define a protocol for its own delegate methods. Setup your table view controller to be each cell's delegate.

One of the protocol methods would be a method asking the delegate to present a view controller on its behalf.

Your cell protocol would have a method such as:

```
- (void)cell:(CustomTableViewCell *)cell presentViewController:(UIViewController *)controller;
```

Your custom cell's `takePhoto` method you do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self.delegate cell:self presentViewController:picker];        
}
```

Then your table view controller would implement the method:

```
- (void)cell:(CustomTableViewCell *)cell presentViewController:(UIViewController *)controller {
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Thanku @rmaddy I forgot all about the delegates :(