# Send mail from CollectionViewCell.swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to send a mail from the collection view cell controller, but I get error. Here is full code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MessageUI

import Parse
import Bolts

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var uploadedTimeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var currentUserLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var flagContentButton: UIButton!

    var deviceID = [String]()

    var parseObject:PFObject?

    @IBAction func buttonClick(sender: AnyObject) {
        println(deviceID)

        let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
        }
    }

    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["test@email.com"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("Test subject")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Test mail!", isHTML: false)

        return mailComposerVC
    }

    func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        sendMailErrorAlert.show()
    }

    // MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Error line:

```
self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Error code:

> 'CollectionViewCell' does not have a member named
>   'presentViewController'

Any suggestions what to do here?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829035/open-camera-from-uitableviewcell-ios for a similar issue and relevant solution.

Comment: @rmaddy - Yes, to use this `self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`. I get same error..

Comment: `self` needs to be a view controller.

Comment: @rmaddy - How do i set self as a view controller?

Comment: Did you read the question and answer I linked to? It explains it all.

Comment: @rmaddy - I have never used Obj-C at all.

Comment: Don't read the code then. Just read the description of what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You could use completion blocks or a delegate to notify the view controller, like below. You would set either `delegate` or `notifyViewController` on the cell in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. This way, you can tell each cell which controller you want to handle presenting the mail controller and the controller can decide how to do it.

```
protocol CollectionViewCellDelegate {
    func notifyViewController(mailViewController: MFMailComposeViewController)
}

class CollectionViewCell: ... {
    //...

    var delegate: CollectionViewCellDelegate?

    // you could use this completion block property in place of a delegate
    var notifyViewController: ((MFMailComposeViewController) -> Void)?

    //...

    @IBAction func buttonClick(sender: AnyObject) {
        println(deviceID)

        let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            delegate?.notifyViewController(mailComposeViewController)
            // OR
            notifyViewController?(mailComposeViewController)
        } else {
            self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Nothing is happening when pressing `buttonClick`, only the println function.

Comment: Did you set either the `delegate` or the `notifyViewController` to anything? Does a view controller somewhere set this code and then do `presentViewController(...)`? This is merely a means of communication between the cell and a view controller; not a magical answer for presenting view controllers.

Comment: It should be correct, i have set both: http://s3.postimg.org/ohco65az7/Screen_Shot_2015_10_05_at_19_20_43.png and http://s12.postimg.org/b2gtufjdp/Screen_Shot_2015_10_05_at_19_21_07.png

Comment: In the second screenshot, you are defining a new variable, delegate, instead of assigning a value to the cell's delegate. It should look more like `cell.delegate = self`, and then you need to implement the delegate function there to display a view controller. I am assuming `self` here is a `UIViewController`.

Comment: How can i show a alertView in the `CollectionViewCell class`? With Yes and No button?

Comment: `UICollectionViewCell` cannot present a `UIAlertController`. This must be presented from a `UIViewController`. So your collection cell should notify a `UIViewController` that it wants to present an alert controller. You can do this with the delegate pattern i mentioned above, use a completion block like i mentioned above, use notifications, or any other form of communication between objects. There are lots of answers to that question.